# Converting OBJ with textures to USDZ using Reality Converter

Tags: augmented-reality, realitykit, reality-converter

I'm trying to convert `.obj` with several `.png` (textures) files into `.usdz` through Reality Converter but it isn't working. It'll take the object, but when I put the png files under the material folder, nothing happens?

Any suggestions?

I end up with a blank/white object.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue myself, but don't worry. In the main preview, it doesn't reflect the texture after adding a `png` file, but if you watch the small preview on the left side (click the <kbd>Models</kbd> button), it correctly displays the texture. Therefore, if you export it, the `usdz` file is exported correctly with the texture.

Answer (score 0):

### Reality Converter

OBJ model comes with two corresponding files – texture file (usually `.jpg` or `.png`) and `.mtl` file. The last is an auxiliary ascii file containing definitions of materials that may be accessed by an OBJ file. This definitions' file must be in the same directory as OBJ and its texture. My `.mtl` file (generated in Autodesk Maya) contains the following lines of code:

```
newmtl initialShadingGroup
illum 4
Kd 0.00 0.00 0.00
Ka 0.00 0.00 0.00
Tf 1.00 1.00 1.00
map_Kd texture.jpeg
Ni 1.00
```

As you can see, everything is displayed correctly.

[image]